# Is $(\sqrt{-7})^2$ defined in the real domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Obviously $\sqrt{-7}$ is undefined in the real domain (since $-7 \lt 0$), however I'm wondering if $(\sqrt{-7})^2$ is as well.

Per my understanding, using the following rule (listed in my textbook exactly as written):

$$
\sqrt{a^n} = (\sqrt{a})^n, a \in \mathbb{R},\space n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

we could say (also knowing that $\sqrt{a^2} = \left|a\right|$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$):

$$
(\sqrt{-7})^2 = \sqrt{(-7)^2} = \left| -7\right| = 7
$$

effectively giving

$$
\sqrt{x^2} = (\sqrt{x})^2 = \left|x\right|, x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Is this approach correct? (the final answer is clearly wrong - but the approach per my initial understanding follows all aforementioned rules).

Comment: The rule you cite is not valid.  $\sqrt{a^n} \ne (\sqrt a)^n$.  That is not a rule.

Comment: $\sqrt{-7}$ is a complex number $=i\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: @fleablood Actually such a rule works just fine when both expressions are defined in the real numbers, since both expressions should equal $a^{\frac{n}{2}}$. The problem is that we can't extend it to this case because we're dealing with expressions not defined in the real numbers, so the rule fails.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Perhaps my choice of words was poor: I understand that $\sqrt{-7}$ is not a real number, I was wondering if its square is, and if my approach for getting its result was correct (turns out - it's not).

Comment: @bool3max You cannot square a real which does not exist.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Right. So the moment I did $(\sqrt{-7})^2$ (assuming I'm working within the real number set only), I performed an invalid operation?

Comment: By definition $\sqrt {-7}$ is the complex number $a$ so that $a^2=-7$. So your number is -7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textbook (?) error starts from here:

$$\sqrt{a^n} = (\sqrt{a})^n, a \in \mathbb{R},\space n \in \mathbb{N}$$

The right rule should be like this:

$$\sqrt{a^n} = (\sqrt{a})^n, a≥0,\space n \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Solution-verification**

Is this approach correct?

$$\sqrt{x^2} = (\sqrt{x})^2 = \left|x\right|, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

No, it is not correct.

The correct rule should be as follows:

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2}& = (\sqrt{x})^2 = \left|x\right|=x, ~ \text{where}~ x≥0.&\end{align}$$

This implies, the following approach is also invalid:

$$\begin{align}(\sqrt{-7})^2 = \sqrt{(-7)^2} = \left| -7\right| = 7\end{align}$$

The correct approach might be as follows:

$$\begin{align}(\sqrt{-7})^2
&=(\sqrt {7i^2})^2\\
&=(i\sqrt 7)^2\\
&=i^2\times 7\\
&=-7.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{-7} = i\sqrt{7}$ is obviously a complex number. $(i\sqrt{7})^2 = -7 \neq 7$

The rule ($\sqrt{a^n}=(\sqrt{a})^n$) which I had used in my question only works if both expressions are defined in the real number set (i.e. when $a \ge 0$ in this case). Since $\sqrt{-7} \notin R$, the rule does not apply and my approach is wrong.